# What should I learn in order to understand ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm able use some basic ffmpeg commands to process videos, but I never fully understood them. There are too may terminologies in ffmpeg's documentation that I don't understand. What should I learn so that I can read ffmpeg's document by myself? I want to learn the video audio structure and other basic knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resource should help you with what you need to know https://opensource.com/article/17/6/ffmpeg-convert-media-file-formats